Como agregar una fecha en el formulario de registro de evento en odoo
quiero agregar un campo para poner una fecha de nacimiento en el formulario de registro de un evento,ya tengo puesto que sea para una fecha de nacimiento pero me lo pilla como una entrada de texto,alguien sabe como seria?



Pudiste resolverlo? Parece que es una vista qweb la que tienes que modificar.  Tampoco pones en que versión de odoo estas, actualmente odoo le da mantenimiento a 3 versiones, pero en uso hay desde la 13 hasta la 17, y tienen muchas diferencias.
